# Sending an empty multipart file from angular6 to springboot

Tags: spring-boot, angular6, multipartform-data

I want to send an image file to spring boot back end. When the image is upload the post request working fine.But if there is no image file uploaded it gave me an error.

I tried to send null if the user doesn't upload any image. But it gave me an error.

Here is my onSubmit function

```
onSubmit() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    if ( this.addEntityForm.value.entityCode !== '' &&  this.addEntityForm.value.entity !== '' && this.addEntityForm.value.eDisplayName !== '') {

      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('name',this.addEntityForm.value.entityCode);
      formData.append('description',this.addEntityForm.value.entity);
      formData.append('displayName',this.addEntityForm.value.eDisplayName);
      if (this.selectedFile != null){
        formData.append('logo', this.selectedFile);
      }
      else {
        formData.append('logo', null);
      }
      formData.append('status','ACTIVE');

      console.log(formData);

      this.profileServise.addNewEntity(formData).subscribe( result => {

        if (result) {
          this.globalService.updateEntityTable(result);
        }
        this.openSnackbar('New Entity Created Successfully');
        this.matDialogRef.close();
      }, error => {
        this.openSnackbar('An Error in Creating a New Entity');
      });
    } else {
      this.openSnackbar('Please fill all required fileds !!!');
    }

  }
```

This is my function I used to choose the image.

```
onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

This is my back end controller method

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addNewEntity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<CompanyDTO> photoUploaded(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "description", required = true) String desc,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "displayName", required = true) String displayName,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "logo", required = true) MultipartFile logo,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "status", required = true) String status
    ) {

        // getting file extension
        String fileExtension = logo.getOriginalFilename().substring(logo.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".")+1);

        //convert to bytes
        byte[] image = new byte[0];

        try {
             image = logo.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Company company = new Company();
            company.setName(name);
            company.setDescription(desc);
            company.setDisplayName(displayName);
            company.setLogo(image);
            company.setStatus(status);
            this.companyService.saveCompany(company);
            log.debug("edited entity"+company.getName());


        CompanyDTO newrow = new CompanyDTO(company.getId(),company.getName(),company.getDescription(),company.getDisplayName(),company.getLogo(),company.getStatus());

        return new ResponseEntity<>( newrow,HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

I am sending 'null' if the user doesn't choose an image. It gave me this error

````
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'logo' is not present```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are marking the API POST parameter as `required=true`, if a parameter is optional and can contains `null` value, you need to mark that as `required=false`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNewEntity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<CompanyDTO> photoUploaded(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "description", required = true) String desc,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "displayName", required = true) String displayName,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "logo", required = false) MultipartFile logo,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "status", required = true) String status
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. This answer solved my problem. And again it gave me an null point exception. I handled it as follows, ``` byte[] image = new byte[0];

        if (logo != null){
            //convert to bytes
            try {
                image = logo.getBytes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```